.Net MQ client can't connect to MQ over TLS CWSMQ0006E with reason 2538
We have an MQ server running and I'm trying to connect to it using XMS. Using .Net6. I can connect to an usecure channel and read it. But when connecting to another secure channel, I run into problems.
I do have a valid certificate imported into Windows cert store (using mmc).
The server is using CipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.
My code to accomplish the connection is:
                XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
                IBM.XMS.IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
                cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "hostname");
                cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
                cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channelname");
                cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "manager");
                cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);
                cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");

                IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();

I then get error IBM.XMS.XMSException: 'CWSMQ0006E with reason 2538. Linked exception is MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE.
In the MQ server logs I get the following:
The SSL or TLS connection was closed by the remote host '255.255.255.255' during
the secure socket handshake. The channel is '????'; in some cases its name
cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Check the remote end of the channel for SSL and TLS errors. Fix them and
restart the channel.

I don't understand this error as I do specify CipherSpec. I do also have a valid certificate in the Windows key store. I read a lot, about specifying a path to a kbd file but I have to idea how to export the certificate to an kbd file.
From my understanding is that that the application can't find my certificate and can't do a proper handshake due to mismatched cipherspec. I did try several cipherspecs, none of them works.
If I need to provide more info, please let me know.
UPDATE:
As I assumed this is a certificate issue and the server is set up to accept only TLS 1.2/1.3, I created a kdb file with the personal certificate which I added to it, with command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\bin\gsk8capicmd.exe" -cert -add -db test.kdb -type kdb -label ibmwebspheremqusername -trust enable -file personal.cer

When running validation of this certificate, I got the following error:
CTGSK2146W An invalid certificate chain was found.
Additional untranslated info:
GSKKM_LAST_VALIDATION_ERROR: No certificate chain built

I then added the signed trust certificate to the same kdb store and when I run the validation on both certificates I get OK for the signed trust certificate, but the following error for the personal one:
CTGSK2052W An invalid basic constraint extension was found.
Additional untranslated info:
GSKKM_LAST_VALIDATION_ERROR: GSKVAL_ERR_CA_MISSING_CRITICAL_BASIC_CONSTRAINT (575051)

When I run the C# code, I get:
{"CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381. During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component. See the linked exception for more information."}

The linked exception is
MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR

It's kind of expected as the validation of the certificate in kdb file fails
SOLUTION UPDATE:
For me the issue was that the certificate in the Windows certificate store was wrongly imported. What I ended up doing is creating an p12 cert store file, importing certificate and key files, assigning a label in the form of ibmwebspheremq+username and then importing it to the Windows certificate store.
The final code I ended up with was just:
        XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
        IBM.XMS.IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "hostname");
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channelname");
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "manager");
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");


What version of MQ is running on the server? What version of MQ are the MQ dlls from. Does the windows key store trust the queue manager cert?  .Net6 is managed mode. You need to specify the windows cert store location to use,  for the machine store use *SYSTEM, for the user's store use *USER (both are the actual string to use). For example cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*USER");.  If you use the machine cert store you need to ensure the user has permission to the cert.

Hi, MQ serverside is 9.3, IBMXMSDotnetClient is 9.3.2. I tried both *USER and *SYSTEM but both yield the same result. The connection gets aborted at a failed handshake so could it be that the .net client is not using TLS 1.2/1.3 (only ones allowed on server side). Certificate has been added to the certificate store at certificates/personal/certificates, I would guess that is in the user's store? I believe Windows 11 is using TLS 1.3 by default, not sure about IBMXMS v9.3.2, but how do I make sure it's indeed using TLS 1.2/1.3? Also what is the diff between Win key store and certificate store?

Try as a troubleshooting step changing the SVRCONN to have SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) SSLPEER('').  If you get past the connection error then you know it has something to do with the client side cert.  Do you see the cert you added when you run certmgr.msc (*USER) or when you run certlm.msc (*SYSTEM)?  If the later you need to expand Personal/Certificates, right click on the cert you added,  hover over 'All Tasks' and then select "Manage Private Keys...", from there you can make sure your application user has Read access or add that permission.

Please see the update in the main post. I assume that the previous error was caused by SSL issues so I added a kdb file and am now pointing to it. I do get validation errors which leave me clueless

Can you confirm which dlls from MQ  you reference? I think you are running in managed mode which doesn't use kdb files.

In de bin directory I see 2 dll's, amqmdnetstd.dll and amqmxmsstd.dll. I now have a working personal certificate with which I made a connection from MQ Explorer. I'm now a bit lost on how to put the personal certificate and key file in a kdb keystore, if that's what I need to use. Connection mode is now configured as XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT. If I change it to WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED the I immediately get ": XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE is not supported in this release." Which keystore should I use in managed mode? PKS #8? Thank you

I looked it up in the documentation and indeed in managed mode I should use a p12 keystore. I created a p12 where I added the trusted root certificate and the personal keypair (also used to connect using MQ explorer) and I now get MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR. When running validation command (gsk8capicmd.exe) I get "Invalid basic constraint extension was found" error. So now I'm kind of stuck at this

If you are on windows the cert needs to go in the windows key store.   The dlls you referenced only work in managed mode.  .net on windows can not use p12, that is only .net on Linux.

Thank you for your time. So I now added the root certificate in root trusted root certification and the personal certificate to personal certificate repository. What I get now is "The conversation cannot begin because a certificate has not been supplied by
the remote partner.
If this error message is written on the receiving side of the channel, then the
channel attributes 'SSLCAUTH' caused the check to be made."

Did you review the details I provided Oct 1st?  Did it work with SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) SSLPEER('')?  Is the error you provided from the queue manager?  What is the friendly name of the personal certificate?  If you don't specify a cert label in the CF it will by default look for ibmwebspheremq, I would suggest changing the cert's friendly name to match what is expected.

Thank you for your time. The managed code and need to use the Windows certificate store put me on the right track. I edit my post with the solution that worked for me
